# Get the Column names of a table in Web-Sql

Tags: html, cordova, web-sql

I am trying implement a mobile app by using phonegap.I will get the tables from server side using RestFul api.Here i want to get the column names of a particulat table.

I have seen other posts but no body has given the answer with respect to web sql, Please help me.

Comment: Is it possible to get column names of table in web-sql?